# Java protected variable access and modify rules

Tags: java, android

For Android, I have a class called AFrag, I'm wondering if it is possible to create protected field that's accessible to the sub classes (ex.BFrag), and then the super class can access the reference that the sub class assigned to the protected field.

```
public class AFrag extends Fragment
{
     protected EditText someEt;...
}

public class BFrag extends AFrag
{
     @Override
     onCreateView()
     {
          someEt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextinBFragXml);...
     }
}
```

BFrag is loaded within AFrag as a childFragment. when I'm accessing the variable in AFrag, like someEt.getText() would throw NullPointerException. My question does the reference to the BFrag's xml exist back in AFrag?

My use case is I have multiple dynamically loaded fragments with its own unique sets of UI EditText views, and I would like to have a single parent fragment that hosts the "Save" button that would call getText() on all the views in each child fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected variable can accessible in subclass when it is in the same package.If BFrag is in different package then you can not access the super class protected variable in subclass.

Comment: The fragments are in the same package, my question is whether the superclass would be able to access the reference that the subclass set to the protected variable. In my use case superclass's variable is still null, after the subclass initialized it.

Comment: "my question is whether the superclass would be able to access the reference that the subclass set to the protected" - > No super class can not access variables which are there in subclass even it is a public variable.

 "In my use case superclass's variable is still null, after the subclass initialized it" - >

Comment: "In my use case superclass's variable is still null, after the subclass initialized it" - >`public class BFrag extends AFrag
{
     @Override
     onCreateView()
     {
          someEt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextinBFragXml);...
     }
}`  you are trying to initialize super class variable to subclass.Please check what value is coming in code (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextinBFragXml)

Comment: `protected` means accessible to subclasses even if they're not in the same package. This answer is wrong when it (confusingly) says "If BFrag is in different package then you can not access the super class [sic] protected variable in subclass."

Answer (score 0):

In `BFrag` the `rootView` is current Fragments view and not `AFrag` 's rootView

So you will get `NullPointerException` , because in `BFRag`, `someEt` does not exist

But as far as variables are concerned, you will be able to refer. With the fact that your Super Class should exist in Application memory

Comment: NullPointerException is throw from AFrag when AFrag accesses the variable (ex. getText()) , the variable's reference is set within BFrag.

Comment: Idea is the same, Ive explained the other way around